# Map the below Json in Apex

Tags: apex, json

Can someone help to map the below Json in Apex.
The code i used is only works till the fisrt level, when used the second level as list it gives null.

```
String json1=       '{'+
        ''+
        '" GetCustomerCommitmentResponse": [{'+
        ''+
        '"Commitment": {'+
        ''+
        '"Service": "MQAC2AH/A",'+
        ''+
        '"Description": "iPhone X 64GB Space Grey",'+
        ''+
        '"Type": "Commitment",'+
        ''+
        '"Period": "24",'+
        ''+
        '"DisconnectionFee": "50.833",'+
        ''+
        '"StartDate": "2018-10-25",'+
        ''+
        '"EndDate": "2020-10-25",'+
        ''+
        '"DaysLeft": "130",'+
        ''+
        '"MonthsLeft": "4.0"'+
        ''+
        '}'+
        ''+
        '}]'+
        ''+
        '}';
```

---

```
Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(json1);
system.debug(results);
List<Object> RtInfo3 = (List<Object>)results.get('GetCustomerCommitmentResponse');
system.debug(RtInfo3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only an accidental blank at the beginning of the `GetCustomerCommitmentResponse` in the json1 String.

Remove the blank, `RtInfo3` is showing.

Comment: Thanks lot Xi Xiao. It worked!